# Derivative of log determinant and inverse

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, determinants, matrix-theory, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix $\Sigma$ with element $(i,j)$

$$\Sigma_{i,j}= \exp(-h_{i,j}\rho).$$

The matrix is positive definite and symmetric (it is a covariance matrix).
Now I need to evaluate
$$\frac{\partial \log(\det(\Sigma))}{\partial \rho} \text{ and } \frac{\partial \Sigma^{-1}}{\partial \rho}.$$

Someone can help me?

Comment: orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: I have this pdf, but i don't understand how use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*modified according to the clarification given in comments*].

In general, for an invertible square matrix $\Sigma=\Sigma(\rho)$, differentiably depending on the real variable $\rho$, we have: $(\Sigma^{-1})'=-\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma' \Sigma^{-1}$, and $\big(\det(\Sigma)\big)'=\operatorname{tr} (\Sigma^{-1}   \Sigma')\det(\Sigma)$, so that 
$\big(\log \det(\Sigma)\big)'=\operatorname{tr} (\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma')$.

Here, $\Sigma'$ is the matrix with entries $-h_{ij}e^{-\rho h_{ij}}$, the Hadamard product of the matrices $-(h_{ij})_{ij}$ and $\Sigma$; and since both  $\Sigma^{-1}$ and $\Sigma'$ are symmetric, $\operatorname{tr} (\Sigma^{-1} \Sigma')$ is just their Frobenius scalar product. I do not see other simplifications, unfortunately.

Comment: No! it'isn't.It is for work.

I have some problem with your answer. Why $\Sigma^{-1}=exp(\rho H)$. For what i know, this is true for a diagonal matrix, but this is not the case.

P.S. $H$ is positive definite, symmetric and its diagonal has all value equals to 1
  

Comment: Think on the power series of exp(x) and exp(-x), and why exp(x)exp(-x)=1. 

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't understand. Let me use an example. If H is a 2×2 matrix with element (i don't know how to write a matrix so i write its elements)
(0, 1 ,1, 0)  (before i made a mistake, the diagonal elements are 0 and not 1). If $\rho=2$, $\Sigma$ is (1, 0.1353353, 
0.1353353 ,1 ). Using the formula $\Sigma^{-1}=exp(\rho H)$ I obtain                        
 (1, 7.389056 ,7.389056 ,1), while using a software to obtain the inversion, i have                            
 (1.0186574, -0.1378603,
 -0.1378603 ,1.0186574).                              
Where is the problem?

Comment: In the original question, $\Sigma\neq \exp(\rho H)$. Here, each entry is exponentiated, while the matrix exponential is defined by inserting a matrix into the power series expansion of the exponential.

The problem as stated, Niandra, is a bit harder. I don't have an answer, and doubt there is a clean one. Is it possible you meant/need the matrix exponential instead?

Comment: No, what I wrote is what I have. 

I know i can use, for a generic matrix the following: $\frac{\partial log(det(\Sigma))}{\partial \rho}= TR(\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \rho})$ and
 $\frac{\partial \Sigma^{-1}}{\partial \rho}=-\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \rho}\Sigma^{-1}$.
 I' not sure if these can be applied to covariance matrix or if with symmetric matrix there is another formulation 

Comment: Ah, I see. That should work just fine, I forgot about Jacobi's formula for a second. If something works for a "generic matrix" is should work for most matrices (here, as long as your matrix function is invertible in a neighborhood of $t$, but the problems if it isn't are obvious). Often times, you can make algorithms faster if you are working with symmetric matrices (say in MatLab), but the generic procedure should work as well.

Comment: The matrix cookbook orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf, at page 14, states the following: "Assume that the matrix A has some structure, i.e. symmetric, toeplitz, etc. In that case the derivatives of the previous section does not apply in general". In the previous section there was the two formula i wrote before. I try to understand why and how to find the solution to my problem but i have some difficulties. Someone can help me?

Comment: actually the notation is a bit unclear to me. I understand $\Sigma= \exp(\rho H)$; or do you really mean that $\Sigma$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is equal to $\Sigma_{ij}=e^{h_{ij}\rho}$?

Comment: I mean the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is equal to $\Sigma_{i,j}=e^{-h_{i,j} \rho }$ 